# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x17037e760)

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, function-call

So I'm learning C and the task is to find the best football player out of those listed in a txt file, this error pops up everytime I try to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct FUDBALER {
    char name[20];
    char surname [30];
    int goals;
    int assists;
    
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    struct FUDBALER fudbaleri[20];
    
    fp=fopen("/Users/mirkopopovic/Desktop/fudbaleri.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) printf("fajl ne postoji");
    else {
        while(scanf(fp,"%s,%s,%d,%d", &fudbaleri[i].name, &fudbaleri[i].surname,&fudbaleri[i].goals,&fudbaleri[i].assists != EOF))
        {
            printf("%s,%s,%d,%d",fudbaleri[i].name,fudbaleri[i].surname,fudbaleri[i].goals,fudbaleri[i].assists);
                    printf("\n");
                        i++;
        }}
    int a=0,b=0,c,d;
    
    //Searching for the best one
    
    for(int j= 0; j<i; j++) {
        a = fudbaleri[j].goals + fudbaleri[j].assists;
        
        if(b<a) { b=a; c=j;}
    }
    d= b/5;
    printf("Najbolji fudbaler je %s %s sa %d bodova:", fudbaleri[c].name,fudbaleri[c].surname,d);
}
```

I'm on Mac and I'm using Xcode if it helps

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler, elevate warnings to errors, and pay attention to them. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Answer (score 0):

In the call of scanf

```
while(scanf(fp,"%s,%s,%d,%d", &fudbaleri[i].name, &fudbaleri[i].surname,&fudbaleri[i].goals,&fudbaleri[i].assists != EOF))
```

the forth argument is the expression

```
&fudbaleri[i].assists != EOF
```

The comparison with EOF must be after the closing parenthesis of the function call.

Also the first and second arguments must be written like

```
fudbaleri[i].name, fudbaleri[i].surname
```